# Passing arguments to mock method

Tags: python, mocking

I'm brand new to unit testing and mock. I would like to have a mock method append to a dictionary, but I'm not sure how I can accomplish this. I need to pass key and value arguments to `append_dict`. Using this, I get

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Code:

```
def mock_client(dictionary):
    client = mock.MagicMock()
    client.dictionary = dictionary
    client.append_dictionary(key, value) = client.dictionary[key] = value #this line doesn't work
    return client
```

The function is called in the file I want to test like so:

```
client.append_dictionary(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the method directly and set it to the `client` object:

```
def mock_client(dictionary):
    client = mock.MagicMock()
    client.dictionary = dictionary

    def append_dictionary(self, key, value):
        self.dictionary[key] = value

    client.append_dictionary = append_dictionary
    return client
```

On the other hand, if you wish to test whether `append_dictionary` is called properly in your code it may be better to do something like this:

```
mocked_client = mock_client({})
my_code(mocked_client)
self.assertEqual(
    mocked_client.append_dictionary.call_args_list,
    [
        mock.call("key", "value"),
    ]
)
```